# Want item in listview to send to another class

Tags: java, android, class, listview

I want just for now the first item in a listview to open another class.
The brands class on which the code is on opens fine, but if I click on a listitem it just stops working.
I get no errors from Android Studio so I don't know where to begin

Here is my code:

```
public class brands extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.brand_list);
    setTitle("Order By Brand");

    final ArrayList<Brand> brands = new ArrayList<Brand>();

    brands.add(new Brand("Black Label",R.drawable.black_label,R.color.black_label));
    brands.add(new Brand("Castle Lager", R.drawable.castle_lager,R.color.castle_lager));
    brands.add(new Brand("Castle Lite",R.drawable.castle_lite,R.color.castle_lite));
    brands.add(new Brand("Castle Milk Stout",R.drawable.milk_stout,R.color.castle_milk_stout));
    brands.add(new Brand("Hansa Pilsner",R.drawable.hansa,R.color.hansa));
    brands.add(new Brand("Flying Fish",R.drawable.flying_fish,R.color.flying_fish));
    brands.add(new Brand("Lion Lager",R.drawable.lion_lager,R.color.lion_lager));
    brands.add(new Brand("Redd's",R.drawable.redds,R.color.redds));
    brands.add(new Brand("Brutal Fruit",R.drawable.brutal_fruit,R.color.brutal_fruit));

    BrandAdapter adapter = new BrandAdapter(this, brands, R.color.order_by_brand);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            ListView black_label = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            black_label.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent black_labelIntent = new Intent(brands.this, black_label.class);
                    startActivity(black_labelIntent);
                }
            });
    }}
    );
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are trying to open a non activity class. You should provide an activity class that declared in manifest when creating your intent.

Change your onItemClick implementation like this.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent black_labelIntent = new Intent(brands.this, <the_activity_you_want_to_open>.class);
            startActivity(black_labelIntent);
    }}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use listview it is not suggested by google recyclerview is "smarter" the answer is already there by santalu